# How do I set a table background color in a PDF file with MigraDoc?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

```
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table tAzul = section.AddTable();
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Column colAzul = tAzul.AddColumnMigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Unit.FromCentimeter(20));
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Row rowAzul = tAzul.AddRow();
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Cell cellAzul = rowAzul.Cells[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `Shading`.

This can be done for a cell:

```
row.Cells[1].Shading.Color
```

IIRC the shading can also be set for rows and columns - or for the table.

Edit:
Here's a sample line that sets the color of a table:

```
tAzul.Shading.Color = Colors.LightYellow;
```

Comment: Might you give me an example of how to set the background of my "tAzul" table?